# ExtJS 4, How to manually refresh pagination in Grid from Store (locally)

Tags: pagination, grid, extjs4

I work with ExtJS 4.1, MVC. For the first time, after page is loaded I download data to grid and then I want to work with it locally. I can add records to the grid and manually delete them.

When I try to delete one record, I manually delete it from store (I checked store), but text in pagination is previous. I can see changes on store and on grid, but text in pagination tool is like it was before deleting.

So how can I refresh that text manually?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it should be automatic but you can fix it with pagingtoolbar.doRefresh( ) , or firing the change event of the binding store.fireEvent("change")